Reproducción de video en saltos y cíclico
En cada tarjeta muestro un vídeo como una demostración (como hace los resultados de búsqueda de Google), lo cual se reproduce en modo muted y en saltos de 1 minuto; al terminar el video, se repite el salto de 1 minuto  (Esto, cuando doy un click a un botón para voltear la tarjeta y ver el video y los detalles).
El problema que tengo y no puedo solucionar es:

en el navegador solo reproduce el primer salto y no avanza
cuando está en reproducción y salgo de la página (sin cerrar) y vuelvo, en la consola me da errores.

Este el error en consola:
Uncaught (in promise) AbortError: the play() request was interrupted because vudeo-only background media was paused to saved power. https://goo.gl/LdLk22

Ahora que inserte un enlace de vídeo online para el demo, funciona, pero aún así no del todo bien.


const video = document.querySelector("video");
const duracionSalto = 60;
 const intervalo = 5000;
 const duracionTotal = video.duration;
 let tiempoInicial = 0;
 let intervaloId;

(function reproducirSaltos() { 
   
   video.currentTime = tiempoInicial;
   video.play();
   
   setTimeout( () => {
    
video.pause();
tiempoInicial += duracionSalto;
    
if(tiempoInicial >= duracionTotal) {
 tiempoInicial = 0;
}
    
reproducirSaltos();

   },intervalo);
   
  })();
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
video {
 display: block;
 width: 100%
}
<body>
    
<video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" muted="true" controls></video>

</body>




puedes hacerlo asi:


class VideoPreview {
      constructor(containerId) {
        this.container = document.getElementById(containerId);
        this.video = this.container.querySelector("#previewVideo");
        this.progressBar = this.container.querySelector(".progress-bar-fill");

        this.previewPoints = [];
        this.totalPoint = 6;
        this.currentPreviewIndex = 0;
        this.previewInterval = null;

        this.setupVideo();
        this.setupEventListeners();
      }

      setupVideo() {
        // Configurar el video
        this.video.volume = 0;
        this.video.currentTime = 0;

        // Cuando el video está listo, calculamos los puntos de preview
        this.video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
          const duration = this.video.duration;
          // Crear 4 puntos de preview a lo largo del video
          for (let i = 0; i < this.totalPoint; i++) {
            this.previewPoints.push(duration * (i / this.totalPoint));
          }
        });
      }

      setupEventListeners() {
        this.video.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
          this.startPreview();
        });

        this.video.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
          this.stopPreview();
        });

        // Reiniciar el video cuando termine
        this.video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
          this.currentPreviewIndex = 0;
          this.video.currentTime = this.previewPoints[0];
        });
      }

      startPreview() {
        this.currentPreviewIndex = 0;
        this.video.currentTime = this.previewPoints[0];

        this.previewInterval = setInterval(() => {
          this.currentPreviewIndex =
            (this.currentPreviewIndex + 1) % this.previewPoints.length;
          this.video.currentTime =
            this.previewPoints[this.currentPreviewIndex];

          // Actualizar la barra de progreso
          const progress =
            (this.currentPreviewIndex / (this.previewPoints.length - 1)) *
            100;
          this.progressBar.style.width = `${progress}%`;
        }, 800);
      }

      stopPreview() {
        clearInterval(this.previewInterval);
        this.currentPreviewIndex = 0;
        this.video.currentTime = 0;
        this.progressBar.style.width = "0%";
      }
    }

    // Inicializar el preview cuando la página cargue
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const preview = new VideoPreview("videoContainer");
    });
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.video-preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.video-preview:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.controls-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.play-icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.play-icon::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid white;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.progress-bar-fill {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 0.3s linear;
}

.video-info {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.video-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.video-meta {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #606060;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
<div class="video-container" id="videoContainer">
    <div class="preview-container">
      <video
        id="previewVideo"
        class="video-preview"
        muted
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        playsinline
      >
        <source
          src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>

      <div class="controls-overlay">
        <div class="play-icon"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-fill"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-info">
      <p class="video-title">Kenzie Reeves </p>
      <p class="video-meta">Canal • 1M vistas • hace 2 meses</p>
    </div>
  </div>




Funciona muy bien. Pero no es mucho código ? Y no reproduce el salto como video, si no como un flash back de fotos
